# SMS notifications delivered in background

Tags: messages, notifications, sms

I have issues with SMS messages not being delivered to me prominently most of the times. Notifications are turned on:

- Allow Notifications is on
- Lock Screen is checked
- Notification Centre is checked
- Banners is checked
- I even have "Repeat Alerts" set to 10 times.

All of this still doesn't deliver SMS messages to me in the foreground. Basically, whenever my phone is locked and I receive an SMS, the phone screen does not light up and no sound or vibration is played.

For certain contacts, I even have emergency bypass turned ([Use Focus on your iPhone or iPad - Apple Support (AM)](https://support.apple.com/en-am/HT212608)) because it is very important that I am made aware of SMS messages I receive from these contacts, but it's no use.

Has anyone else experienced this? Any settings I can experiment with?

Note: I also asked this question [on the apple discussions forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/254970291), but I am looking for as much input as possible.